# How does Rellich–Kondrachov not lead to a contradiction?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm currently working through Lawrence Evan's PDE's textbook, and in it, he states the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem:

Assume $U$ is a bounded open set of $\mathbb R^n$, and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Suppose $1 \leq p < n$. Then
$$W^{1,p}(U) \subset \subset L^p(U)$$
for each $1 \leq q < p^*$ where $p^*$ is the Sobolev conjugate of $p$.

I am currently failing to see how this does not contradict the fact that a linear space is compact if and only if it is finite dimensional. In particular the argument I have in mind is that, if $\overline{W^{1,p}(U)}$ is compact, then so is the unit ball in $W^{1,p}(U)$, being a closed subset of a compact set. But, $W^{1,p}(U)$ is clearly not finite dimensional.

Where does the above argument go wrong? Thanks!

Edit: After doing some further digging, it seems like the main cause of my confusion is that the topologist's definition of compact embedding and the analyst's definition are not equivalent, so I was under the impression that the theorem said something that it didn't.

Comment: In what topology is $\overline{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}$ compact?

Comment: "a linear space is compact if and only if it is finite dimensional" -- a *normed* linear space is finite dimensional iff its closed unit ball is compact, via Riesz's lemma, say. Seems by your logic, compact subsets of infinite dimensional spaces shouldn't exist at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An embedding $X\subset Y$ being compact means that if we

1. consider the image of the unit ball of $X$ under this embedding, and
2. take its closure *in the topology of $Y$*,
3. then we'll get a compact set *in the topology of $Y$*.

None of this speaks of the closed unit ball of $X$ being compact in the topology of $X$. And it will not be, unless $X$ is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

According to Evans (paraphrasing slightly):

**Definition:** Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces with $X \subset Y$.  We say that $X$ is **compactly embedded** in $Y$, written $X \Subset Y$ provided both:

1. There is a constant $C$ for which $\Vert x \Vert_Y \leq C \Vert x \Vert_X$ for all $x \in X$.
2. Every **bounded** sequence in $X$ has a subsequence which converges in $Y$.

The qualifier "bounded" in (2) is important.  In writing $X \Subset Y$, we are **not** asserting that **every** sequence in $X$ has a subsequence which converges in $Y$.  That is: It does not follow that $\overline{X}$ (the closure of $X$ in the topology of $Y$) is compact (in the topology of $Y$).

Comment: Ok, but this does not seem to quite avoid the problem. Every sequence in B(0,1) is bounded and hence contains a convergent subsequence. Since B(0,1) is additionally closed, this would seem to imply that it is compact. It seems like it's actually condition 1 that avoids the contradiction.

Comment: @stats_model No: if you take $X=Y$, $\lVert x\rVert_Y=\lVert x\rVert_X$ for all $x\in X$ (since $\lVert\cdot\rVert_X$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_Y$ denote the same norm). Then $C=1$ (that is, 1. is always satisfied), but 2. is not satisfied when $X=Y$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: That every sequence in a closed unit ball $B(0,1)$ contains a convergent subsequence is false, take a separable Hilbert space and an orthonormal basis for instance. Condition 1 is there to say the inclusion operator $\iota: X \to Y$ is bounded, which comes way before one tries to prove a compact embedding since the inclusion is typically proven by boundedness (Sobolev inequalities).